# How to make speech recognition in python faster?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm currently working on a "smart" assistant project in Python3 on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
The only problem is that the "speech_recognition" is very slow (maybe 4 or 5 seconds). I want to lower the time it takes to process.

I have looked into the Google Cloud API and IBM, but they are obviously not free. How fast is `pocketphinx` on a Raspberry Pi? Is there another way to speed this up?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Speech Recognition` Python package. That comes with lot of Options for Speech Recognition. even `Google` Speech recognition can be used Freely or try to use The Open Source Speech Recognition  [DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) from Mozilla.